# Simple classification problem between real and fake data always gives zero loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Hey I have just started with machine learning and was trying to classify between real (**label 1**) and fake data (**label 0**). Here is the code that I have written. The `real_loss` and `fake_loss` is always zero. Intuitively, I would assume it would go to zero over time, but not from the first epoch. Can someone please correct me, where I am going wrong.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

#generate n samples with class labels
#1 --> real data class name
def gen_real_samples(n):
    
    #generate samples from the function
    x = np.random.rand(n) - 0.5 #domain of input to f(x) is [-0.5, 0.5)
    y = func(x)
    
    #reshape
    x = x.reshape(n, 1)
    y = y.reshape(n, 1)
    
    data = np.hstack((x, y)) #data
    labels = np.ones((n, 1)) #lables
    
    return data, labels

#generate n samples with class labels
#0 --> fake data class name
#both x and y are in between [-1, 1)
def gen_fake_samples(n):
    
    #generate samples from the function
    x = 2 * np.random.rand(n) - 1
    y = 2 * np.random.rand(n) - 1
    
    #reshape
    x = x.reshape(n, 1)
    y = y.reshape(n, 1)
    
    data = np.hstack((x, y)) #data
    labels = np.zeros((n, 1)) #lables
    
    return data, labels

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    
    #initialize the NN layers in this module
    def __init__(self, n_inputs=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=n_inputs, out_features=25),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), #has no tunable params, can define in forward()
            nn.Linear(in_features=25, out_features=1),
            nn.Sigmoid() #has no tunable params, can define in forward()
        )
        
    #operations on the input data
    def forward(self, x):
        model = self.model(x)
        return model

def train_Discriminator(model, n_epochs=1000, n_batch=100):
    
    #define the loss and the optimizer
    d_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    d_optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    
    half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)
    
    for k in range(n_epochs):
        
        #generate real samples and update model
        real_data, real_labels = gen_real_samples(half_batch) #real
        out = model(torch.Tensor(real_data)) #forward pass
        loss = d_criterion(out, torch.Tensor(real_labels)) #compute the total loss
        loss.backward() #backward pass (compute parameter update)
        d_optimizer.step() #make the updates for each parameter
        d_optimizer.zero_grad() #a clean up for pytorch
        
        print(f'real_loss: {loss}')
        
        #generate fake samples and update model
        fake_data, fake_labels = gen_fake_samples(half_batch) #fake
        out = model(torch.Tensor(fake_data)) #forward pass
        loss = d_criterion(out, torch.Tensor(fake_labels)) #compute the total loss
        loss.backward() #backward pass (compute parameter update)
        d_optimizer.step() #make the updates for each parameter
        d_optimizer.zero_grad() #a clean up for pytorch
        
        print(f'fake_loss: {loss}')

def main():
    model = Discriminator()
    train_Discriminator(model)
```

Tried settings requires_grad = True and change numpy to tensor in the gen_real_data and gen_fake_data. But that also did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you certain its incorrect. Is it possible the fake data is so different from the real data that it's obvious at first sight to your model?

Comment: I do not completely understand your point. But yes, my real data's domain is bt. [-0.5, 0.5) and the fake is bt. [-1, 1).

Comment: In generate_real-

Comment: gen_real_data generate random number in bt. [-0.5, 0.5) and then feeds it to x ** 2. So essentially its a parabola. Where as gen_fake_data generate random number bt. [-1, 1).